# Form validation in multiple records in for loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have here an php records, I have an edit page for multiple records and has form validation. My problems is in my for loop for calling multiple records.

[image]

Just like in the picture above,my PR# textbox had a message even the two PR# that has id of 000174 and 000176 have a correct input. How to make my validation works for only textbox that has an invalid inputs per ID.

Help please?

```
<form name="register_form" id="register_form" action="" method="post">

<?php
$id=$_POST['checkbox'];
$drop=$_POST['drop'];
$tier_two=$_POST['tier_two'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
SELECT a.item_name, a.item_description, a.counter, b.counter, b.pr, b.total_quantity
FROM app a
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_request b
ON a.counter=b.counter
WHERE a.counter='$id[$i]'
    ");
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
      { ?>
<p> <label for="">ID</label> <input name="counter[]"  type="text" value="<?php echo $row['counter'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/><span class="val_counter"></span> </p>             

    <p> <label for="">Item</label> <input name="item[]"  type="text" value="<?php echo $row['item_name'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/><span class="val_item"></span> </p>               

    <p> <label for="">Description</label> <input name="desc[]"  type="text" value="<?php echo $row['item_description'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/><span class="val_desc"></span> </p>             

    <p> <label for="">PR Quantity</label>
            <input name="pr_qty[]" id="pr_qty[]"  class="textbox tb1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['total_quantity']; ?>" />
            <span class="val_pr_qty"></span>
    </p>        

    <p> <label for="">PR #</label> <input name="pr[]"  type="text" value="<?php echo $row['pr'] ?>" /><span class="val_pr"></span> </p>             
<br/>
      <?php
      }
}

?>

<input name="submit" type="submit" id="sbtBtn" value="Update">
</form>
```

And this is my **Script**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;

    $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {

    var validation_holder = 0;

        var item                = $("form#register_form input[name='item']").val();
        var item_regex          = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check    
        var desc                = $("form#register_form input[name='desc']").val();
        var desc_regex          = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check    
        var pr_qty              = $("form#register_form input[name='pr_qty']").val();
        var pr_qty_regex        = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check
        var pr                  = $("form#register_form input[name='pr']").val();
        var pr_regex            = /^[0-9]+$/; // reg ex qty check
        var counter             = $("form#register_form input[name='counter']").val();
        var counter_regex       = /^[0-9]+$/; // reg ex qty check

        /* validation start */  

        if(item == "") {
            $("span.val_item").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!item_regex.test(item)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_item").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_item").html("");
            }
        }

        if(desc == "") {
            $("span.val_desc").html("");
        } else {
            if(!desc_regex.test(desc)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_desc").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_desc").html("");
            }
        }

        if(pr_qty == "") {
            $("span.val_pr_qty").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!pr_qty_regex.test(pr_qty)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_pr_qty").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_pr_qty").html("");
            }
        }

        if(pr == "") {
            $("span.val_pr").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!pr_regex.test(pr)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_pr").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_pr").html("");
            }
        }

        if(counter == "") {
            $("span.val_counter").html("");
        } else {
            if(!counter_regex.test(counter)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_counter").html("Please Refresh to avoid database error!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_counter").html("");
            }
        }

        if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 
}); // jQuery End
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the id of span tag is same for every record,so if error is there in any record it will be reflected in the span tag of every record.Use different id for every record is the solution...

Comment: but how I can change that if the records is in loop?

Comment: append the value of i to the id from the for loop....something like this...-><span id='val_desc_'.i ...></span>

Comment: you are using class instead of id in span tag...please look into it

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop every input like that

```
$("input:text[name=counter]").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: check every value if ( $(this).val() == '' ) { echo 'Please insert counter'return false; } in your loop

Comment: why I use echo in jquery?